# Why System.currentTimeMillis() is slow on Linux?

Tags: java, performance, time, milliseconds

I want to calculate response time of every method.This can be done with System.currentTimeInMillis but I have heard it is slow on linux.

Can anyone explain why is it slow?

Comment: Answer is available here http://pzemtsov.github.io/2017/07/23/the-slow-currenttimemillis.html

Answer (score 4):

## `java.time.Instant.now()`

> This can be done with System.currentTimeInMillis

That method `System.getCurrentTimeInMillis` is supplanted by `Instant.now()`.

In most implementations of Java 9 and later, you will find `Instant` captures the current moment with a finer resolution of microseconds, for six digits of decimal fraction versus three. To be clear, `Instant` can represent a moment with even finer resolution, nanoseconds, but captures the current moment with micros. Today’s conventional hardware cannot track time accurately at nanos resolution.

## `System.nanoTime()`

> I want to calculate response time of every method.

For micro-benchmarking, use `System.nanoTime`. This method tracks an endless loop of nanoseconds passing by, but has *nothing* to do with the current date-time.

Be aware that micro-benchmarking is tricky. Results are likely to be unreliable when performed by novices.

For serious micro-benchmarking, consider using the [*JMH*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) framework.

## Avoid `System.currentTimeInMillis`

> …System.currentTimeInMillis but I have heard it is slow on linux.

I have no idea what might have prompted that statement. I suspect you misunderstood.

At any rate, the issue is moot. No one need ever call `System.currentTimeInMillis` again in modern Java.